# Using the SD card with the Seeed Studio TFT Touch Shield 2.0

Tags: arduino, screen, storage

I just purchased Seeed's TFT Touch Shield 2.0 for Arduino, but I cannot seem to figure out how to access the SD card while maintaining the ability to draw to the screen.  The tutorials and documentation are quite insubstantial (for me), and most questions on the product site seem to be directed to the same [wiki page](http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/2.8%27%27_TFT_Touch_Shield_V2.0), which doesn't explain anything about the SD interface, other than what example file draws bitmaps from the card.

I've used the SD interface with the Ethernet Shield before, but it's been a long time since then, so I can't quite remember the ins and outs.  From my old code, it seems that, for normal usage of the SD library, you simply do:

```
#include <SD.h>

void setup()
{
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

    if (!SD.begin(4))
    {
        //Fail
    }

    ...  //Open file, read, etc.
}
```

To use the TFT screen normally (with the exception of drawing bitmaps), you do as such:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <TFTv2.h>
#include <SPI.h>

void setup()
{
    TFT_BL_ON; //Enable Backlight

    Tft.TFTinit(); //Initialize TFT Screen

    Tft.drawCircle(100, 100, 30,YELLOW); //Draw
}
```

In the provided example program on the wiki page for drawing bitmaps from the SD card, the setup code looks like this:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <TFTv2.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define chipSelect 4

Sd2Card card;

void setup()
{
  pinMode(11,INPUT);
  pinMode(12,INPUT);
  pinMode(13,INPUT);
  TFT_CS_HIGH;
  pinMode(chipSelect,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(chipSelect,HIGH);

  Serial.begin(38400);
  SPI.begin(); 
  Tft.TFTinit();
  //SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
  //SDcard_info();
  /**/
  DDRB |= 0x04;
  card.init(SPI_FULL_SPEED,chipSelect);
  if(!SD.begin(chipSelect))//SPI_QUARTER_SPEED,
  { //53 is used as chip select pin
    Serial.println("failed!");
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.println("SD OK!");

  Tft.setCol(0,239);
  Tft.setPage(0,319);
  Tft.sendCMD(0x2c);//start to write to display ram
  TFT_BL_ON;
}
```

In `loop()` bitmaps are sequentially opened with `SD.open()`, drawn, and then closed with `SD.close()`.

What I assume is happening is that pins 11 through 13 are set to input for some SPI-related reason, the TFT chip select 'enabled' mode is set to HIGH, and then the screen is subsequently enabled.  Serial moniter is started, followed by SPI, and then the TFT.  After those things happen, it does something unknown to me, starts the card, and then uses the standard card initialization method.  It finishes up by preparing to draw the bitmaps and sends this 'command 0x2c', which is used frequently in the underlying libraries to "start to write to display ram".

The problem is that I have tried initializing the TFT and SD card using this code, and then attempted to draw graphics as shown in my second example, but this did not work.  I need to be able to read bytes from the SD card, and then be able to draw simple graphics on-screen, and repeat.

So my question is: Is anyone who has used this shield before or has experience with this able to explain how one should go about writing the code to allow usage of both the SD card and screen or how the initialization and SPI processes work to make this possible?

Thanks for your answers in advance!

(Also, if this is not the correct SE site for this question, please feel free to migrate it accordingly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem is quite simple actually, and I must have been doing something wrong when I had combined the source files before.

The initialization code looks like this:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <TFTv2.h>
#include <SPI.h>

Sd2Card card;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(11, INPUT); //Pin mode changes; not sure what for
    pinMode(12, INPUT);
    pinMode(13, INPUT);
    TFT_CS_HIGH; //Something with chipselect and the TFT
    pinMode(4, OUTPUT); //Set chipselect pin to OUTPUT
    digitalWrite(4, HIGH); //Set chipselect mode

    SPI.begin(); //Start SPI
    Tft.TFTinit(); //Initialize the TFT
    TFT_BL_ON; //Turn on the TFT Backlight
    Serial.begin(9600); //Start serial output

    DDRB |= 0x04; //Some sort of processor IO port?
    if(!SD.begin(4)) //Start the SD card
    {
        while(true) { } //Fail
    }
}
```

It is basically the bitmap initialization code, with the extra TFT commands at the end left out.  After this, both the screen and the SD card are usable, as was desired.

Comment: I had to down vote because you seem very unsure of what the code does to work. Try to do more research and tell us why it works now.